# Why is my BlackBerry exception getMessage() returning null?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm using the following line of code in all of my catch statements to print errors to the console:

```
System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE " + e.getMessage() );
```

Sometimes, in the console, I get the following:

```
ERROR MESSAGE null
```

How can it be null? If it reaches the catch that means an exception was thrown, but why null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why it is null, I just suppose that BlackBerry OS and API has a lot of undesired behaviour. I solved this issue by using

> e.toString()

as in:

```
catch (Exception e)
{    
    System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: e.toString() seems ok so far, still can't figure out why the message would be null some of the time though. Thanks

Comment: Not all exceptions thrown by BlackBerry OS, or some programs set the message value, so it is null by default. At least toString() will give you the class name of the actual exception thrown. Usually that is enough.